# Cannot update an B2C local user profile photo on Azure portal/ using Graph with application issued token

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I have B2C local accounts and when I'm trying to get/update their profile infos using Graph API with aplication issued token, it worked.
But when I try to get/update their profile photo, I get 404 errors.

request: (GET)

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userOid}/photo](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BuserOid%7D/photo)

response: 404

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ImageNotFound",

    "message": "Exception of type 'Microsoft.Fast.Profile.Core.Exception.ImageNotFoundException' was thrown.",

    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-10-26T16:12:52",

      "request-id": "ac24acee-8317-4d77-95ea-c69df189e7cb",

      "client-request-id": "ac24acee-8317-4d77-95ea-c69df189e7cb"
    }
  }
}
```

request: (PUT/POST) and setting the content type as well

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userOid}/photo/$value](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BuserOid%7D/photo/$value)

response: 404

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",

    "message": "{\r\n \"errorCode\": \"ErrorUserResolutionFailedUserDoesNotExist\",\r\n \"message\": \"Exception of type 'Microsoft.Fast.Profile.Core.Exception.ProfileNotFoundException' was thrown.\",\r\n \"target\": null,\r\n \"details\": null,\r\n \"innerError\": null,\r\n \"instanceAnnotations\": []\r\n}",

    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-10-26T16:13:55",

      "request-id": "3517b374-a08d-41a1-8f68-9c9da3cbfb3b",

      "client-request-id": "3517b374-a08d-41a1-8f68-9c9da3cbfb3b"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are using Microsoft Graph REST API V1.0 to get/update user photo for B2C local accounts.

**But these operation in version 1.0 supports only a user's work or school mailboxes and not personal mailboxes**

So you can use Microsoft Graph REST API beta version to get/update user photo for B2C local accounts.

**When getting / updating the user photo using beta version, this operation first attempts to get / update the photo in Microsoft 365. If that fails (due to the user not having a mailbox), this API will attempt to get / update the photo in Azure Active Directory**

**Note : For updating profile photo for users, use only PUT operation.**

For getting the profile photo of user, please make sure the user has profile photo in the Azure AD. Else, it will throw **ImageNotFound** error.

**Reference** :

[profilePhoto resource type - Microsoft Graph beta | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/profilephoto?view=graph-rest-beta)

[profilePhoto resource type - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/profilephoto?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Thanks @RamaraoAdapa-MT for answering me, I've used the beta version as you suggested but still getting the same error. I don’t understand why user profile photo cannot be updated on Azure portal directly.

Comment: you are not able to update the profile photo in the Azure  Portal also? What error are you getting if you try to update the profile  photo in the portal?

Comment: Yes, look at the image bellow.
![](https://i.ibb.co/hV2XnjG/Screen-Shot-2021-10-28-at-10-45-56.png)

Comment: which type of account are you using  to get / update the  profile photo? You should use only work or school account with User.ReadWrite, User.ReadWrite.All delegated permissions

Comment: I'm using work account with User.ReadWrite, User.ReadWrite.All delegated permissions

Comment: We can move this discussion to chat room. please join using the below link : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238653/b2c-local-account-update